# Extracting "Proportion of variance explained" from summary(rda) for axis labels

Tags: r, vegan

I'm looking to plot an RDA and have the axis labels automatically populate with the proportion of variance explained by the proportion of variance explained from the summary output. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to call that specific object.
Example to work with:

```
a<-as.matrix(varespec)
b<-as.matrix(varechem)
R<-rda(b,a)
summary(R)
R2<-RsquareAdj(R)
P2<-anova(R)
title<-paste("P=", P2$`Pr(>F)`, "R2=",R2$r.squared)
plot(R,type="n",bty="n",main= title,
     xlab="{var RDA1}% variance explained", 
     ylab="{var RDA2}% variance explained", 
     col.main="black",col.lab="black", col.axis="white",
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
abline(h=0,v=0,col="black",lwd=2)
points(R,display="species",col="gray",pch=20) 
points(R,display="cn",lwd=3)
text(R,display="cn",cex=0.5)
```

In that example, I'd want to replace {var RDA1} with the value for "Proportion Explained" from the "Importance of components:" section under columns RDA1 and RDA2 respectively (columns 1 and 2, row 2 respectively). I just can't seem to figure out how to reference those specific values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are computed by `summary(R)` so you have to save them as an object:

```
R.sum <- summary(R)
R.sum$cont   # Prints the "Importance of components" table
R.sum$cont$importance[2, "RDA1"]
# 0.74785
R.sum$cont$importance[2, "RDA2"]
# [1] 0.19804
```